# SharePoint 2013 onclick not firing - loading # instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, onclick

I've got a column with a URL set to execute a function on click, but when I click it, it goes adds a # to the end of the url instead of executing the function. The URL is registering as:

```
<a onclick='OpenLandLRegistration(1)' href='#'>Register</a>
```

Here's the javascript code:

```
function OpenLandLRegistration(event_id){

var eventurl ="/Lists/Events/DispForm.aspx?ID="+meeting_id;

 var options = {

      url:"/Lists/Attendees/Item/newifs.aspx?List=%7B9E2217C5%2DE878%2D406D%2DB25A%2D2FA7EAADFC17%7D&meeting_id="+meeting_id,

      width: 750,

      height: 600,

      dialogReturnValueCallback: DialogCallback

 };

//SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
window.open(eventurl);

}

function DialogCallback(dialogResult, returnValue){  }
```

EDIT:: Here is a working example of what I'm trying to do: 
[link](http://tinyurl.com/ob638zs)

The javascript converts the link to html and the executes the function on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent a link from firing, just add a `return false;` at the end of your `OpenLandLRegistration()` function.

Also the problem could be coming from the fact that in this example, at least, the `meeting_id` variable you're attempting concatenate with "/Lists/Events/DispForm.aspx?ID=" is undefined, so it'll throw a reference error and exit immediately.

Also worth noting that nothing is happening with `options` either, beyond it getting defined.

Have you heard of [Firebug for Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/)? It's an excellent debugger for javascript that can really help you step through bugs as you work through things like this.

Comment: I added the return false, and it still didn't open the URL. Where can I see the reference error? 

I have firebug, but I'm not sure how to use it to check what's wrong since it's not explicitly throwing an error - just not executing properly. 

I added a link to a working example of what I'm trying to do.

The "Register" link actually renders as plain text (if you check the html source), is converted to html and then fires the onclick event.

Comment: If you actual code mirrors the example above, the reference error should be thrown in the console. Just make sure firebug is open (press  F12 to fire it up )

(I used a undefined variable called undefinedVar for the purpose of this example)
[See firebug example](http://i.imgur.com/m28Qd0l.jpg)

Comment: I got the reference error, but I'm not sure how to fix it. The meeting_id is a number assigned to each item in the SharePoint list.

Comment: Does it relate in some way to the event_id parameter? I'm pretty sure one you figure out how to actually set the meeting_id variable,your problem will be solved.

Comment: The event url was incorrect. It should've been the options URL.

    The following code worked:

    function OpenLandLRegistration(meeting_id){

    var eventurl ="/sites/gt/er/Lists/Attendees/Item/newifs.aspx?List=%7B9E2217C5%2DE878%2D406D%2DB25A%2D2FA7EAADFC17%7D&meeting_id="+meeting_id; window.open(eventurl); return false; }